# Magento 2: Sync inventory of Associated products

Tags: magento2

We have several sizes under one product. We have one product which can be sent as XS & S, another one which can be sent as M or L. We want to be able to sync inventory for XS & S and M & L. Thanks in advance

Comment: What type of products? Is that about sync stock of simple products associated to configurable? Please expand the details

Comment: We have one configurable product and 6 simple under it as sizes (Technically: Associated products). A customer can buy Small, Medium, Large or XL. We want to be able to reduce qty of Medium also when someone buys Small. Similarly, reduce XL when L is bought. THanks